# CreateChildControls fires before <EventHandler> in CompositeControl

Tags: asp.net, web-controls

I have a big problem with a CompositeControl that is really making me sick!

I create my control tree in `CreateChildControls` method, which is ensured in the `Render` event.
One of this controls is a `LinkButton` with an `<EventHandler>` attached. In this event I would like to save the values of other controls (TextBox) in Session before recreating them.

I have a similar CompositeControl that works, but for some weird reason this one is not working as expected. `CreateChildControls` fires BEFORE the LinkButton's `<EventHandler>`, so I lose the TextBox's values.

Any idea? I am going crazy!!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question with a tip for you all:

> ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWAYS assign IDs to your controls!!!!!!!